# Why process switching does not make our computing experience discontinuous

Tags: operating-systems

We are all aware that CPU is switching between processes it is running, but how come we never experience any discontinuation while CPU is switching and we are using applications?

I would say this is because of the sheer speed of the switches between processes, but I am curious about how many processes would really impact the performance of a CPU to a point where humans would experience discontinuation (or breaks) on a single application and how would it manifest on modern operating systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would say this is because of the sheer speed of the switches between
>   processes

You are correct. But still the operations being performed by microprocessor are being performed in discrete steps and not in a continuous way. Every clock cycle makes the CPU fetch the contents of memory pointed to by program counter. In next clock cycle it decodes the instruction and so on. If you can become fast enough (to notice), you can notice that the music you think is continuous actually plays for some time and then stops then plays again and so on.

**The fast and complex beast** that makes the process of switching blazing fast is called Short term scheduler (CPU scheduler). It must be fast because it’s being invoked every few millisecond’s and it’s not doing any useful work (from user’s perspective). Although different implementations may have slight differences, almost all scheduler’s maintain priority queue’s for different classes of processes such as active, background etc.

So even if thousands of processes were running on a computer, only few of them would be directly interacting with the user. Schedulers take this information in account when switching processes. Because an update checking process can wait but real time music streaming can not.

> But I am curious about how many processes would really impact the
>   performance of a CPU to a point where humans would experience
>   discontinuation

There is no magic number and there are so many other factors that affect the performance (memory speed, size etc). I think you will run out of memory before scheduler performance becomes any issue. One thing that can manifest itself as break outs is when some high priority interrupt routine is being invoked and it’s being executed for long time.

**Fun fact**: - To make user experience better on a system (I forgot) Steve jobs directed the apple engineers to assign mouse interrupt the highest priority so that pointer doesn’t lag while moving.